# Bind to a property of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a class "A".
This class A have an object B.

I have a datagrid. On this datagrid, i bind severals A properties.
I would like to bind in addition a B propertie.

I tried this :

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ Binding B.strDes}" Header="   Libellé type évènement   " Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  />
```

My problem is there is no value displaying.

B is an object propertie, and strDes is a B propertie.

How can i do it simply in xaml please ?

Comment: i don't see a problem with your xaml, except for the space infront of the Binding. Please show us your classes A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this syntax

```
{Binding ElementName=B,  Path=strDes}
```

Note : Don't forget the source

```
DataContext="{Binding Source=yourData}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example and it works fine:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="DataGridBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectAList}">      
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ Binding ObjectB.strDes}" Header="   Libellé type évènement   " Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
   public List<A> AList { get; set; }

   public MainWindow()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      AList= new List<A>();
      AList.Add(new A());
      AList.Add(new A());
      AList.Add(new A());
      AList.Add(new A());
      DataContext = this;
   }
}
```

And the Classes A and B:

```
public class A
{
   public B B { get; set; }

   public A()
   {
      B=new B();
   }
}

public class B
{
   private static int counter = 0;
   public string strDes { get; set; }

   public B()
   {
      strDes = "foo"+counter;
      counter++;
   }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Edit: 
A hint for check your binding. Set TraceLevel to "High" for getting more information about it:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{ Binding B.strDes, PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Header="   Libellé type évènement   " Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  />
```